# Custom Recipe on a Cookbook

Tags: linux, chef-infra

I'm developing a custom recipe using the package packages from chef.

I created a file under the recipes folder called apache.rb.

Then I uploaded the cookbook through berks and I edited the recipes list on one node with recipe["packages::apache"].

When i run the chef-client I got the following error:

```
could not find recipe apache for cookbook packages
```

This is the apache.rb located under recipes/ folder:

```
    package 'Install Apache' do
    case node[:platform]
    when 'redhat', 'centos'
      package_name 'httpd'
      version '2.2.0'
    when 'ubuntu', 'debian'
      package_name 'apache2'
    end
    action :install
    end
```

Comment: Is it really uploaded successfully?

Comment: it is. no error with berks upload.

Comment: Is berks pulling your `packages` cookbook or the supermarket one ? (I guess there's something around this, you should avoid names present in supermarket. Here we prefix our cookbooks with company name).

Comment: And I mean don't modify a community cookbook,  do a wrapper cookbook including the community cookbook a'd override it's attributes and rewrite resources when needed, add your own recipe including the community cookbook and doing extraneous things

Comment: @Tensibai I guess this is the best solution. Do you have some example online about wrapping cookbooks?

Comment: Did you try a Google search on 'chef wrapper cookbook' ? I'll probably won't give anything better, try it and ping me, I'm on phone and will give a link tomorow if you didn't find something by yourself ;)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `knife upload . --force`, to make sure the cookbook is really up-to-date on the chef server?

There might be an older version of the cookbook already uploaded (i.e. before you created the apache recipe), and because you've kept the version number in `metadata.rb` the same, knife (or berks, depending on what you use for the upload) might be skipping the upload, thinking nothing's changed.

UPDATE:

It should be noted that the above should really only be used if you are *really* sure you want to update the *existing* version on the Chef Server (e.g. if you are still in development).

Bumping the version number on the cookbook's metadata would be a **much better** way to solve this problem for production environments, as pointed out by @Tensibai in the comments below.

Comment: Better recommend bumping the version than using force ... Downvoting as  promoting a bad practice even if it could solve the OP's problem (for chef-servers open source before 11.1 IIRC)

Comment: @Tensibai do you mean change the version in the metadata.rb? It was the first upload I don't if it solves the problem. I will check you and let you know.

Comment: @Tensibai would agree if this wasn't **clearly** in development... in fact, I would argue that bumping versions is terrible practice for development... : )

Comment: I would argue the opposite as  anything uploaded should not be anymore in dev. Test-kitchen with chef-zero has bring far enough to not mess with the server. And knife or berks never skip. The upload is tested by sha256sum on the server side to Know if the file has to be updated. Here the side case could be an old client basing the pull of the new cookbook o' the metadata.rb last change. Clearing the cache on the target node would be enough if really needed, but here we're trying divination in versions used :/

Comment: @Tensibai if you're saying that chef server should only ever be used for production, then I think you're missing out on the time period where you're still learning how it all works and you're bringing out in production status  ; ) 
In any case, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @fmtn07 well, now `chef-zero` exist and allow you to bump an in memory chef-server with all functionalities to test in isolation, there's not really a valid reason anymore to upload multiples times to the chef-server without bumping the version. (I don't remember if  `--force` really enforce an update on the stored cookbook or just break the frozen state of a cookbook, allowing to re-upload with an existing version number).

Comment: agreed!  : )  But even if you somehow do learn that you should start with chef zero first (which is not very clear even from the chef.io tutorials -- they start with chef server!!), you'll still have a migration period when you are preparing your chef server for prod ; )   ... of course, you hopefully won't be facing this type of problems by then!

Comment: @gsaslis Preparing a cookbook and the chef-server are two different things IMO. And increasing the patch number of a cookbook is really the correct way to go. Updating a version with new files is always leading to problems and doubts about what is happening and which instance of the version you get, hence my comment that it's a bad practice to do it. I;e: only those understanding why it is bad and how it could lead to problems should use this method. Teaching correct practice is always better than teaching workarounds with caveats.

Comment: Agreed - except that version bumps are not so practical as you make them out to be... :) that's why we have workarounds as you call them - and imho workarounds are just as important in our job... You often need to have more than one ways to get things done, so you can focus at issue at hand ;)